# Why does cout not display the string variable rnd?

Tags: c++, string, infinite-loop, cout

When I try to display the randomly generated string rnd with cout, I only get endlines as output. Why is this and how can I fix it? On a side note, the while statement creates an infinite loop. Am I not comparing the strings correctly? I am using the g++ compiler.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string str;
    string rnd;
    int x;

    cout << "What do you want the string to be?" << endl;
    cin >> str;

    srand(1);

    //assign the initial random string
    for(int i = 0; i < str.size(); i++)
    {
        x = rand() % 26 + 97;
        rnd[i] = static_cast<char>(x);
    }

    cout << rnd << endl;

    //change individual characters of the string rnd until rnd == str
    while(str != rnd)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < str.size(); i++)
        {
            if (rnd[i] == str[i])
            {
                continue;
            }
            else
            {
                x = rand() % 26 + 97;
                rnd[i] = static_cast<char>(x);
            }
        }

        cout << rnd << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add `rnd.resize(str.size());` after `cin >> str;`. `rnd` does not contain any characters, so you need to resize the string to the same size as `str`.

Answer (score 2):

You never change the size of `rnd`, so it will always be 0. Setting (or getting) rnd[i] when i > rnd.size() is undefined behaviour, but even if it "worked" (say, because your implementation uses the short string optimization and all your words are short), it will never be the case that `str == rnd` because their sizes are different.

I'd suggest:

```
rnd.push_back('a' + rand() % 26);
```

in the initial construction. Inside the `while` loop, you can use `rnd[i]` because by then `rnd` has the right size.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I am trying to use a var and cin, after declaring the variable when you input anything like strings it outputs 0, the variable first of all doesn't have a starting value because the cin will change it into a string but instead the output is 0, I was just testing out this small bit of code so I can reference it for my own custom programming language but this code clearly didn't work:

Code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main(){
int A;
cin >> A;
cout << A;
return 0;
}
```

It is quite small because I was testing this for something, but I don't know why the output for A is 0 and not User-Inputted.